# How to plot the distance between points networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a matrix
[image]

and I draw a graph with that matrix
[image]

How can I show the distance between the points on the graph? Can I use networkx library to handle it ?
Thank you very much

Comment: You are likely to get an answer quicker if, instead of an image, you use text for your matrix. Also, post the code you already have so other users may have something to work with.

Comment: @willcrack ok, thanks. I'll take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
g = nx.Graph()
A = np.array([[0,1,2,3],
              [1,0,2,3],
              [2,2,0,2],
              [3,3,2,0]])
g = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A, create_using=nx.Graph)

pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
nx.draw(g, pos, with_labels=True)
```

After drawing the graph, you have to get the labels using `nx.get_edge_attributes` and label the edges using `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels`.

Like so:

```
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(g,'weight')

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(g, pos, edge_labels=labels)
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: thanks, and how can I draw 3d graph with that graph

Comment: @HenryLe sorry I don’t know. Please accept the answer if it was what you asked for